# both navbars shown on wrong breakpoint

Tags: html, css, sass

My site([www.acweb.com.cy](http://acweb.com.cy)) is having a problem showing the navbar on the top right of the screen. When its resized on at the width of 768px its displaying both the "js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" and the regular navigation bar which is the horizontal for the bigger screens. So when its open on my small ipad is showing both the navbars.

Second off all i dont know much of sass and am using the koala program to edit the templates scss files. Additionally i removed all _(underscore) from the scss filenames cause koala wouldnt read the files. At last when am loading the site and opening the developer inspector within firefox the navbar is read as _navbar.scss instead of navbar.scss as i renamed it.

Thanks for the help!!

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us where the script adding the classes is?

Comment: sorry dont understand you "adding classes".What you mean by that? i told you i dont know sass

Comment: You do not need to know SASS to tell us where the script adding these classes accordingly is. This is done with JavaScript/jQuery, somewhere in a .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your responsive media query codes are colliding at some places, you need to correct that. That's the reason both `navbar` are visible from `768px to 765px`.

This is what your `max-width` and `min-width` are at present as below,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
.......
.....
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.......
.....
}
```

You need to either increase or decrease any one of there width. You can make changes as below,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
.......
.....
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.......
.....
}
```

Comment: if i try to replace "(min-width: $grid-float-breakpoint) "to (min-width: 769px) inside lanbar.scss at line 382 C:\Users\ang3l\Google Drive\elate\sass\bootstrap\navbar.scss koala gives this error
Error: Undefined variable: "$navbar-height".
        on line 13 of C:\Users\ang3l\Google Drive\elate\sass\bootstrap\navbar.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.

Comment: @dll_onFire try making those changes in style.css and not scss.

Answer (score 0):

> So when its open on my small ipad is showing both the navbars.

iPads have a different pixel density than your normal computer monitor, this may be confusing when using css media queries and might even fool your `css` into thinking it's in a totally different `media query`.

I suggest checking out this site to get an idea of why your iPad is showing such a different website than your desktop/laptop:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

For more information about pixel density and specifically Apple's Retina display, this is where you need to be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display

Comment: I think the problem is occurring on any device with 768 px width. I just tested it in Chrome Developer Tools in responsive mode and the problem is still happening.

Comment: offcourse its occuring on an size screen of 768px. I posted this question so that someone would give a solution:)

Comment: Have you tried setting a different DPR in the tools? Responsive is set to a different DPR than the actual retina displays.

You can also add the actual iPad's settings under the Edit... button

Comment: @BRO_THOM The problem is still occurring at different DPR values.

Comment: I see, the media queries are actually overlapping. I also noticed you're using !important rules in CSS, you should try to avoid that by using proper media triggers.

Comment: On a closer look it seems that this is the culprit:

`@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important; <-- this guy is forcing the menu to be displayed via an !important
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;`

In bootstrap.css:3717

Answer (score 0):

**Quick workaround** *(not the best possible solution)*

At the bottom of your main.js file, add this line after all the other methods:

```
$('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('.fh5co-nav-toggle');
```

So that your function will be:

```
// Document on load.
$(function(){

    parallax();

    burgerMenu();

    clickMenu();

    windowScroll();

    navigationSection();

    goToTop();


    // Animations
    homeAnimate();
    introAnimate();
    workAnimate();
    testimonialAnimate();
    servicesAnimate();
    aboutAnimate();
    countersAnimate();
    contactAnimate();

    $('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('.fh5co-nav-toggle');
});
```

This will remove the general class when both of them are used for the navigation.